# How to implement a custom deep ObjectMarshaller<JSON> in Grails?

Tags: json, grails, groovy, marshalling

I'm trying to register a custom JSON marshaller using spring's *ObjectMarshallerRegisterer* bean as described [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/grails-goodness-register-custom.html).

My intention is to capitalize every property name of all classes that implement a certain interface during the marshalling process.

So far, I've implemented this class which is registered as an object marshaller:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.ObjectMarshaller;

class MyMarshaller implements ObjectMarshaller<JSON> {

    @Override
    boolean supports(Object object) {
        object instanceof MyInterface
    }

    @Override
    void marshalObject(Object object, JSON json)
            throws ConverterException {
        def jsonWriter = json.writer

        jsonWriter.object()
        object.class.metaClass.properties.each {
            jsonWriter.key(it.name.capitalize())
            def value = object."${it.name}"
            if(value == null || value instanceof Boolean ||
                    value instanceof Number || value instanceof String) {
                jsonWriter.value(value)
            } else {
                // TODO: Fix this
                jsonWriter.value(JSON.parse((value as JSON).toString()))
            }
        }
        jsonWriter.endObject()
    }
}
```

This class actually works, but I had to insert this line `jsonWriter.value(JSON.parse((value as JSON).toString()))` as a quick fix.

Well, convert the object to a String and then parse it is not a good strategy. There's gotta be a better way to do it. Can you guys help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I searched some grails's sources on github to find out how it's done on the default Marshallers. [this one](https://github.com/gramant/grails-core-old/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/converters/marshaller/json/GroovyBeanMarshaller.java) gave me the answer:

The line on the code above:

```
jsonWriter.value(JSON.parse((value as JSON).toString()))
```

Should be replaced by:

```
json.convertAnother(value);
```

Until now it wasn't clear on the [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.3/api/grails/converters/JSON.html) I found.
Hope this helps someone else with the same issue.